# How to use PHP to Redirect to an url after the base_url

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to redirect to a page 5 secs after an action is done. I've searched up how to use header for this but want to get more info on incorporating base_url() into the code, so I won't need to change this script multiple times on different servers.

Code:

```
$url=base_url().'page_I_want_to_go_to'
header('Refresh: X; URL=$url');
```

This does redirect me to a link, but the url is not the url I was indicating with base and page I want to go to.

Comment: Did you verify that `base_url()` returns the value you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Edit to:

```
$url=base_url().'page_I_want_to_go_to'
header('Refresh: 5; URL=' . $url);
```

Do you have something configured inside the config file. Check the configuration of the framework that uses. For example, in codeigniter the configuration file is in `/application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'my_page';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the bottom line to "double quotes", PHP wont substitute variables that are in single quotes.

```
$url=base_url().'page_I_want_to_go_to'
header("Refresh: X; URL=$url");
```